# How to adjust a TYPO3 extension for newer TYPO3 versions?

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-10.x

I would like to update an extension from the TER to make it TYPO3 v10 compatible. What are the possible solutions and what is the best practice?
Testing and compatibility with older TYPO3 versions should be guaranteed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear if it is your extension or not. So if you are not the maintainer, you should check out the repository on github or gitlab if there is a master or develop branch which might already include the changes you need.

Supporting multiple lts versions with the same code can be very tricky but depends on the type of extension and which parts of the core are used. I prefer supporting maximum 2 lts versions at once (that would be 10 and 9 currently) and supporting older versions with different branches. This makes it easier to move forward.

The extension scanner in the install tool will help you to identify the changes which are required but of course those don't cover everything. A good test coverage in the beginning can help you a lot. If you don't got any tests yet, it is never too late to start with those.

Automated tests can run best on Travis or via github actions and there are lot of examples you can take a look at, eg https://github.com/derhansen/gha_demo or https://github.com/FriendsOfTYPO3/tt_address

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to update a foreign extension.
My current plan is:
Fork the extension, create a new Branch, amend the composer.json file, require the forked extension in a clean bootstrap package extension, use the extension scanner, test all plugins in frontend, run the given test and finally make a commit and create a pull request. What do you think?

Comment: yes that way works. you can also just git pull that extension into either typo3conf/ext/ like your site package or use a packages directory but all options are fine.
Maybe you still wanna accept my answer?